# QLabel is not displaying video

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

It may be a very silly problem, but I am really got stack on this.

Here, I am trying to display a video frame by frame in `QLabel`. In the user interface, there is a `QPushButton` by clicking which user can select the video. Then `QString` of the video file is obtained, which is then converted to `cv::String` so that video can be loaded by using `OpenCV` libraries. After being loaded, every `Mat3b` type frame from the `cv::video` is being converted to the `QImage`, so that these frames can be displayed in a `QLabel`. But when I run this program, the `QLabel` is not displaying the video. And after few moments, it crushes showing `Project.exe is not responding`.
This may be a bit complex, but it has been thus done so that, some specific OpenCV methods can be applied on each frame if needed. Here is some code, which is responsible for this.

```
void MainWindow::on_Browse_clicked()
{
    QFileDialog dialog(this);
    dialog.setNameFilter(tr("Videos (*.avi)"));
    dialog.setViewMode(QFileDialog::Detail);
    QString videofileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open 
    File"), "C:/", tr("Videos (*.avi)"));

    if(!videofileName.isEmpty())
    {
        String videopath;        
        videopath = videofileName.toLocal8Bit().constData();

        bool playVideo = true;
        VideoCapture cap(videopath);
        if(!cap.isOpened())
        {
            QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("Warning"),tr("Error loadeing 
            video."));
            exit(0);
        } 
        Mat frame;

        while(1)
        {
            if(playVideo)
               cap >> frame;

            Mat3b src=frame;
            QImage dest= Mat3b2QImage(src); //To convert Mat3b to QImage

            ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(dest));

            if(frame.empty())
            {
                QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("Warning"),tr("Video frame 
                cannot be openned."));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I added the following few lines before the last three curly brace bracket, both the `QLabel` and `cv::window` are displaying the video.

```
             imshow("Video",src);
             char key = waitKey(10);
             if(key == 'p')
                playVideo = !playVideo;
             if(key == 'q')
                break;
```

But I don't want to display with `cv::window`. Can anyone help me fix it? I appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: add a `QApplication::processEvents();` after you set the pixmap

Comment: Wow, thank you, it works fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GUI thread is busy in the infinite `while` loop, so you never give Qt the chance to update the GUI.

You should add [`QApplication::processEvents`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) inside the loop, which:

> Processes all pending events for the calling thread [...].
>
> You can call this function occasionally when your program is busy performing a long operation